# Pass a promiss to the resolve-Object of an ui.angular Modal-Dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a big problem.
I have some problems with the modal dialog of ui.bootstrap.
What I would like to do. I have a dialog for adding rocker(here called clicker) to my database. When every thing is okay the dialog gets closed, if not it will show an error-message. 
Everything is handled in the controller of the modal-dialog.

Because of my usage of jwt with socketio I had to create a socketio factory that returns a ppromiss. To be able to use the socketio-Instance in my Modal-Controller I have to put it in the resolve-Object of the $modal.

The Problem is, every time I put socketio-Eventhandler in my Modal-Controller, my browser shows me the message that my Controller-Method is undefined.  (No Dialog is showing, only the error-message in the console)

Here is my code. I hope you can help me! I have really no idea how to solve this problem.

**SocketModule.js**

SocketModule is my socketio-Factory that returns the promise. Everywhere else in my code everything works. Only my modal dialog has a problem with this approach.

```
var SocketioModule = angular.module('SocketioModule', []);

SocketioModule.factory('socket', ['$q', '$rootScope', 'socketFactory', '$timeout', '$location', 'AuthHostService',
    function($q, $rootScope, socketFactory, $timeout, $location, AuthHostService) {
        // create a promise instance
        var socket = $q.defer();

        // listen for the authenticated event emitted on the rootScope of
        // the Angular app. Once the event is fired, create the socket and resolve
        // the promise.
        $rootScope.$on('authenticated', function() {
            console.log('received broadcast');
            var protocol    = $location.protocol();
            var host        = $location.host();
            var port        = $location.port();
            var baseurl     = protocol+'://'+host+':'+port;

            // resolve in another digest cycle
            $timeout(function() {
                // create the socket
                var newSocket = (function() {
                    return socketFactory({
                        ioSocket:  io.connect(baseurl, {
                            'forceNew': true,
                            'query': 'token=' + AuthHostService.getToken()
                        })
                    })
                })();

                // resolve the promise
                socket.resolve(newSocket);
            });
        });

        // return the promise
        return socket.promise;
    }
]);
```

**ClickerModule.js**

```
'use strict';

var ClickerModule = angular.module('ClickerModule', ['ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap.modal', 'SocketioModule']);

ClickerModule.controller('ClickerManagerCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$modal', 'socket', function($scope, $location, $modal, socket) {
...

    $scope.openAddClickerModal = function() {
        //Get's the next possible ClickerId from the database
        socket.then(function(socket) {
            socket.emit('clicker:getNextClickerId', {});
        });

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'partial-views/modal_dialogs/addClickerModal.html',
            controller: AddClickerModalCtrl,
            size: 'lg',
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: true,
            resolve: {
                    socket: function(){
                        return socket;
                    }
                }
        });
    };
...
}]);

function AddClickerModalCtrl($scope, $modalInstance, socket) {
    $scope.nextClickerID = 'No ID';
    $scope.input = {};
    $scope.errorMsg = { hide: true };

    //Receives the next possible ID
    socket.then(function (socket) {
        socket.on('clicker:getNextClickerId', function (MsgObj) {
            $scope.nextClickerID = MsgObj.NextClickerID;
        });
    });

    $scope.addClicker = function () {
        if (typeof($scope.input.enoceanUid) !== '' || $scope.input.enoceanUid !== null) {
            socket.then(function (socket) {
                socket.emit('clicker:addClicker', {
                    'enoceanUid': $scope.input.enoceanUID,
                    'clickerName': $scope.input.clickerName
                });
            });
        }
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    socket.then(function(socket){
        socket.on('clicker:addClicker', function(MsgObj){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(MsgObj));

            if(MsgObj.success){
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            } else {
                $scope.errorMsg.hide = false;
                $scope.errorMsg.msg = MsgObj.error.errorMsg;
            }
        });
    });
}
```